# Android: Is it safe to get context from ViewGroup in RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, view, android-context

if i have a RecyclerView adapter like this:

```
public class ResultAdapter extends
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context              context;

@NonNull
@Override

public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    context = viewGroup.getContext();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.challenge_top_user_view_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

}

can i get context by `context = viewGroup.getContext();` in onCreateViewHolder?

Comment: you can just pass in your activity's `context` from your adapter constructor, then use that context instead

Comment: yes you can get context this way